# Some models loaded in a forge viewer do not return any viewport

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a forge viewer loading a document with multiple viewables from a Revit project in BIM360. I can see all viewables rendered just fine. I'm using Autodesk.AEC.ViewportsExtension to display certain elements on the viewer at specific locations, e.g. tags. I managed to successfully show tags by following a [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/ja/node/1765) by Petr, but some viewer models fail to return any viewport.

```
    viewportExt = viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.AEC.ViewportsExtension");
    viewport = viewportExt.getViewports(viewer.model)[0]; // this returns null
    viewportXform = viewport.get3DTo2DMatrix(viewer.model.getUnitScale());
```

this works for some viewables but some don't return any viewports which I need, to translate between 3D and 2D spaces. I can see AEC metadata is loaded in both cases. I am at a loss why only certain views fail to return viewports.

---

I just tried Petr's [sample](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-viewer-samples) with my own models in BIM360. My viewables from the Revit projects are not returning any viewports. I suspect this has something to do with what's happening during BIM 360 publish process.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to our BIM360 user manul [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/BIM360D-Design-Collaboration/files/GUID-0A824636-51A3-4EDC-8152-8D42CFF5616E-html.html), the [Crop View checkbox enabled](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/view/RVT/2020/ENU/-guid-GUID-8BEBCEF0-CE2C-4635-8C7C-9D03503C0B79.html) is required.

- Newly published data. It does not work for previously published models.
- 2D sheets with floor plan views, structural plan views, or reflected ceiling plan views. Other sheets with callout or area plan views are not supported currently.
- Sheets with the [Crop View checkbox enabled](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/view/RVT/2020/ENU/-guid-GUID-8BEBCEF0-CE2C-4635-8C7C-9D03503C0B79.html) in Revit.
- Views without view breaks. Views containing view breaks or view splits are not supported currently.
- Views don't have [Plan Regions](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-594B7B97-0D59-4B03-9544-E403BD03BE48) associated. We can check this by using the following code snippet using Revit API

```cs
var planRegion = new FilteredElementCollector(document).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_PlanRegion).ToList();

planRegion.Any(r => r.OwnerViewId.Value() == planView.Id.Value());

//Before 2024
//planRegion.Any(r => r.OwnerViewId.IntegerValue == planView.Id.IntegerValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, I could get the list of all viewports that are published from Revit projects in BIM 360, including guids of the viewports. However, I still could not get a viewport object for use with the viewport extension, even with findViewportByGuid().

After some research and digging around the model data loaded in the forge viewer, I noticed those published views that I cannot get viewport objects from did not have geometryViewportRegion property, and isCropBoxActive value was set to false.

I am guessing this is why getViewports() returns null for those views. From what I can read from the AEC extension [source code](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/AEC/AEC.js), get3Dto2DMatrix(vp, sheetUnitScale) also requires viewport boundary, so I guess I can't translate from 3D coordinates to 2D coordinates without having viewport boundary explicitly defined for the Revit view.

**I could fix the issue by checking "crop view" checkbox in the Revit view property** for those views, although I was hoping to keep it unchecked so I can have the view published with everything visible without any view boundary.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, the `Crop View checkbox enabled` is required for this case.