# How to get current viewport ID in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I want to draw room polygons onto a DWG background plan using the Autodesk forge viewer. As I learned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588100/transform-point-from-dwg-model-coordinates-to-autodesk-forge-viewer-coordinates), I can get the transformation matrix "pageToModel" like this:

```
model.getPageToModelTransform(viewportId)
```

In the post linked above, the viewport ID is extracted in a quite complicated fashion using a 2D geometry and the vertex buffer reader. Running the proposed code with different DWG files, I realized, that the returned viewport ID was always "1".

Can I rely on the fact, that the current viewport ID is "1" in all cases? If not, is there a simpler approach to get the viewport ID? I want to draw the rooms right after the geometry is loaded and I don't want to force the user to click on a 2D geometry first...

I already tried to use the viewport extension, but as someone else already stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69924465/some-models-loaded-in-a-forge-viewer-do-not-return-any-viewport), I also encountered the problem, that no viewport was returned.

Answer (score 0):

The viewports extension only works for Revit models, unfortunately. The extension read viewport data from [AEC Model Data](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/consume-aec-data-which-are-model-derivative-api), not the 2D drawings.

To make `GeometryCallback` work for multiple models loaded in the same viewer instance, you need to change the model object passed to the `getRenderProxy` funciton. Here is the modified code snippet for your reference:

```
var viewportId = null;
function GeometryCallback(viewer) {
    this.viewer = viewer;
}

GeometryCallback.prototype.onLineSegment = function(x1, y1, x2, y2, vpId) {
    viewportId = vpId;
}

var model = viewer.getAllModels()[0]; //!<<< change the index to switch to other models loaded in the same scene.
var fragId = 0;
var m = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(model, fragId);
var vbr = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexBufferReader(m.geometry, viewer.impl.use2dInstancing);
vbr.enumGeomsForObject(dbId, new GeometryCallback());
```