# Incorrect ModelToSheetTransform in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I use `modelToSheetTransform` in viewports data to map position between 3d and sheet view.
I have 1 3d view with some sheets with it, but 1 of my sheets have wrong position after map, the other sheets are correct. Did I miss some setting in my sheet or was I setting something wrong?

This is my code to map position:

```
const aecData = await Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getAecModelData(
    viewer.model.getDocumentNode()
  );
const viewport = aecData.viewports.find(
      (v: any) => v.sheetGuid === sheetGuid
    );
const sheetUnitScale = viewer.model.getUnitScale();
modelToSheetTransformMatrix = Autodesk.AEC.AecModelData.get3DTo2DMatrix(
        viewport,
        sheetUnitScale
      ).clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the Revit model version generating or saving your Revit model is.

Probably, it's related to a known issue. Could you try to omit the modelToSheetTransform before loading 'Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension' and 'Autodesk.AEC.ViewportsExtension' to see if it helps?

```js
let aecData = viewer.model.getDocumentNode().getAecModelData();
aecData.viewports = aecData.viewports.map( vp => { vp.modelToSheetTransform = null; return vp } );

//Before loading 'Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension' and 'Autodesk.AEC.ViewportsExtension'
```

Viewer will use another approach to calculate the transform, but please ensure your floor plans and sheets are configured with the rules in this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69941583/7745569

If the above doesn't help, please consider providing a test Revit model reproducing this issue to `aps (DOT) help (AT) autodesk (DOT) com` for investigations and pointing out which views can reproduce this issue in the email.

ref:

- https://github.com/yiskang/forge-viewer-hypermodeling-revit/blob/main/public/js/SheetsBrowserExt.js#L279
- https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-viewer-samples/blob/master/public/aec-mapping-2d-to-3d.html#L135

Comment: I found that the sheet that was incorrect is the FloorPlan in Revit. And it does not match the "sheetGuid" in aecData.viewPorts. Do you know any way to calculate the "transformMatrix" of floorplan ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no transform matrix support for only floor plans at present, which means you must place the floor plan on a sheet at least.